# How to resize an image in python using Pillow like photoshops "hard edges" algorithm

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to downsize images with no form of resampling. I want it to fully maintain hard edges, and not add any blur / antialiasing whatsoever. Essentially, exactly like the photoshop "Hard edges" resampling mode. However, each and every one of Pillow's built in resampling methods gives me some kind of blur or aliasing effects.

The code im using currently is as follows

```
fileName = "big.jpg"

for i in range(6):
    filename16 = "small" + str(i) + ".jpg" 
    img = Image.open(fileName)

    img16 = img.resize((16, 16), resample=i)

    img16.save(filename16)
```

Original image:
[image]

The results

Resized image to 16x16 by using;

[image]

Photoshop's "Nearest neighbour - Hard edges"

[image]

0 Pillow Nearest Neighbor

[image]

1 Pillow Lanczos

[image]

2 Pillow Linear

[image]

3 Pillow Bicubic

[image]

4 Pillow Box

[image]

5 Pillow Hamming

[image]

Or side by side, it can be clearly seen that all resampling methods change something about the image

How would i be able to get a result as that achieved by photoshop's "hard edges" option in Pillow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to save your images as .png files. .jpg files are lossy, and don't compress hard lines very well, since they are designed to store regular photos.  If you look at the raw photo data, you will see a sharp transition between zones when you interpolated with `NEAREST`, but since the image is saved as .jpg, that all goes out the window.

---

Here's what the raw data is when you downsize with `NEAREST`:

[image]

Here's what the .jpg data looks like:

[image]

You can see the transition if filled with noise.

Comment: My man, that was exactly the problem. Thanks so much :))